# How to normalize the columns of a matrix in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given a matrix A of dimensions m,n, how would one normalize the columns of that matrix by some function or other process in Julia (the goal would be to normalize the columns of A so that our new matrix has columns of length 1)?

Answer (score 6):

`mapslices` seems to have some issues with performance. On my computer (and v1.7.2) this is 20x faster:

```
x ./ norm.(eachcol(x))'
```

This is an in-place version (because `eachcol` creates views), which is faster still (but still allocates a bit):

```
normalize!.(eachcol(x))
```

And, finally, some loop versions that are 40-70x faster than `mapslices` for the 5x3 matrix:

```
# works in-place:
function normcol!(x)
    for col in eachcol(x)
        col ./= norm(col)
    end
    return x
end
# creates new array:
normcol(x) = normcol!(copy(x))
```

**Edit:** Added a one-liner with zero allocations:

```
foreach(normalize!, eachcol(x))
```

The reason this does not allocate anything, unlike `normalize!.`, is that `foreach` doesn't return anything, which makes it useful in cases where output is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a new matrix then `mapslices` is probably what you want:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> x = rand(5, 3)
5×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.185911  0.368737  0.533008
 0.957431  0.748933  0.479297
 0.567692  0.477587  0.345943
 0.743359  0.552979  0.252407
 0.944899  0.185316  0.375296

julia> y = mapslices(x -> x / norm(x), x, dims=1)
5×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.112747  0.327836  0.582234
 0.580642  0.66586   0.523562
 0.344282  0.424613  0.377893
 0.450816  0.491642  0.275718
 0.573042  0.164761  0.409956

julia> map(norm, eachcol(y))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If by length 1 you mean like with norm 1 maybe this could work

```
using LinearAlgebra

# if this is your matrix
m = rand(10, 10)

# norm comes from LinearAlgebra
# or you can define it as 
# norm(x) = sqrt(sum(i^2 for i in x))
g(x) = x ./ norm(x)

# this has columns that have approximately norm 1
normed_m = reduce(hcat, g.(eachcol(m)))
```

Though there are likely better solutions I don't know!